# Adding a two way authorization in a Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, roles, role-base-authorization, freelancer.com-api

I want to add a two way authorization in my ruby app, just like freelancer has for work and hire. Is there an easy way to do this. In my app there will be two types of users buyer and seller. Seller will have the power to post adds and buyer can bid on them. that's all

Answer (score 2):

For authentication purpose, you can use [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) and for roles (buyer/seller or client/freelancer) management, you have [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan)

You can refer to this tutorial:
[Rails Authentication with Devise & CanCan](http://www.tonyamoyal.com/2010/07/28/rails-authentication-with-devise-and-cancan-customizing-devise-controllers/)